# awk columns to rows break for new line

Tags: text-processing, awk

In my `stats.txt` page I have the following:

```
Get-VMHardDiskDrive | Select-Object Path

ComputerName : ACD-VMH04
Path         : D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\f9314d7d-5d2d-11e0-8feb-806e6f6e6963_2012-06-29T153327.vhd
VhdFormat    : VHD
VhdType      : Dynamic
Used Space   : .07
Prov Space   : 4.00

ComputerName : ACD-VMH04
Path         : D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\C_2012-06-29T153327.vhd
VhdFormat    : VHD
VhdType      : Dynamic
Used Space   : 258.04
Prov Space   : 906.34
```

I run the following `AWK` command to give me this:

```
ACD-VMH04
D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\f9314d7d-5d2d-11e0-8feb-806e6f6e6963_2012-06-29T153327.vhd
VHD
Dynamic
.07
4.00

ACD-VMH04
D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\C_2012-06-29T153327.vhd
VHD
Dynamic
258.04
906.34
```

The file has about 6 items like that however other files have more so I am wondering how to get the output to look like this:

```
ACD-VMH04 - D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\f9314d7d-5d2d-11e0-8feb-806e6f6e6963_2012-06-29T153327.vhd - VHD - Dynamic - .07 - 4.00
ACD-VMH04 - D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\C_2012-06-29T153327.vhd - VHD - Dynamic - 258.04 - 906.34
```

This will somewhat do the job however I do not know how to tell it stop and make a new line when it hits a blank line.

```
awk -F  " : " '{ ORS = " " } /Select-Object Path/ { output = 1; start = NR + 2 }; output && NR >= start { print $2, "-" }' stats.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a one liner for you, but the key concept here is to store the field until you have collected them all, then print them on one line.  Also a blank line will have the number of fields (NF) equal to zero.

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {FS = " : "; OFS = " - "}
NF > 0 {
    gsub(/[ ]+$/, "", $1)
    a[$1] = $2
}

NF == 0 {dump()}

END {dump()}

function dump() {
    print a["ComputerName"], a["Path"], a["VhdFormat"], a["VhdType"]
}
```

**Results:**

```
ACD-VMH04 - D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\f9314d7d-5d2d-11e0-8feb-806e6f6e6963_2012-06-29T153327.vhd - VHD - Dynamic
ACD-VMH04 - D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\C_2012-06-29T153327.vhd - VHD - Dynamic
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne '
   /Select-Object Path/ and !$a++ and <>,next;

   /^ComputerName\s+:/ && $a .. /^$/ || eof and do{
      push  @A, (/\s+:\s+\K(.*)/)[0]          if /^ComputerName\s+:/ || /./;
      print join(" - ", splice(@A,0,@A)),"\n" if /^$/                || eof;
   };

' stats.txt
```

## Output

```
ACD-VMH04 - D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\f9314d7d-5d2d-11e0-8feb-806e6f6e6963_2012-06-29T153327.vhd - VHD - Dynamic - .07 - 4.00

ACD-VMH05 - D:\HYPER-V\VMDEV01\Virtual Hard Disks\C_2012-06-29T153327.vhd - VHD - Dynamic - 258.04 - 906.34
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use " : " as delimter and print 2nd field of every line in awk

```
awk -v FS=" : " -v ORS="" '{{print $2,"- "}; if ( $0 ~ /^$/) {print "\n"}}' stats.txt
```